# Statistics of NDVI mean by shapefile using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics

I am new researcher using GEE and want to use a shapefile (e.g.,Provincial boundaries) to achieve NDVI mean of each province using GEE, how should we do it?

code:

```js
// Create a mosaic of Landsat 5 images from June through September, 2007.
var allBandMosaic = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2016-03-01', '2016-11-30')
  .select('B[0-7]')
  .median();

// Var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([77, 17, 135, 56]);

// Use the normalizedDifference(A, B) to compute (A - B) / (A + B)
var ndvi = allBandMosaic.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);

var palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];


// Center the map
Map.setCenter(103.16, 34.82, 8);

// Display the input image and the NDVI derived from it.
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: palette}, 'NDVI');

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
//Export.image.toDrive({
//  image: ndvi,
//  description: 'ndviToDriveExample',
//  scale: 30,
//  region: geometry
//});
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/qiangsun/shengjie')
  .filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('ENAME', 'Gansu'));
Map.addLayer(fc,{color:'FF0000'},'shenjie');

var means = ndvi.reduceRegions({
  collection: fc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});
means = means.get('ndvi')
print('gansu',means);
```

However, I want to batch process for all provincial mean NDVI in China, and why the result for Gansu is null？.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no access to `users/qiangsun/shengjie` to reproduce the exact error, but supposing that gansu is just one city, you have to use `reduceRegion` instead of `reduceRegions`. And you also have to notice that `Image.normalizedDifference` returns a band called `nd`. You could rename it if you really need it to be named `ndvi`

```js
var means = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  geometry: fc.first().geometry(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});
means = means.get('nd')
print('gansu',means);
```

To compute the mean for all cities use `reduceRegions`

```js
// Remove the filter for Gansu
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/qiangsun/shengjie')
//           .filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('ENAME', 'Gansu'));
Map.addLayer(fc,{color:'FF0000'},'shenjie');

var means = ndvi.reduceRegions({
  collection: fc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});

// the resulting mean is a FeatureCollection
// so you can export it as a table
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: means, 
    description: 'Some Description', 
    folder: 'Some_folder', 
    fileNamePrefix: 'name_of_the_file', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

Comment: i am deeply  grateful for your help, actually, the users/qiangsun/shengjie contains all provinces of China. Gansu is the one of provinces including in the shapefile. and i would like know how to get NDVI mean for each province in China quickly. thank you~~~

Comment: So, did my answer helped you? Is it what you needed?

Comment: I'm afraid not. if i have a shapefile with thousands of polygons, i want to know how to get NDVI mean for each polygon. and export it.

Comment: What did the `reduceRegions` function do? It should do what you are looking for.

Comment: as you said, i do not have any experiences for the reduceRegions function? i learn from others with simple usage. sorry

Comment: That is fine, but what happens when you use the code I propose? doesn't it try to export a csv table?

Comment: the detailed: 1) get a NDVI image in 2016 using landsat 8. and 2）i have a shapefile with  thousands of polygons, and want to count the MEAN of NDVI for each polygon (have objectID), and export the statistical results as a csv table for further analysis. the main question is how to count the MEAN of NDVI for each polygon and export. i

Comment: i have tried and  found a way to get MEAN of NDVI for only one polygon (In code, is Gansu). However, the batch method for each polygon is what i want.

Comment: `reduceRegions` does the batch processing for you. Try with the answer code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a81135779f4f14779c5523159bad818

Comment: @qiangqiangsun I updated the answer. Now should work